# Screen scaling issues with phonegap app on Windows 10 Mobile

Tags: cordova, phonegap-build, windows-10-mobile, cordova-win10

I have a Phonegap Build app that is working fine on iOS, Android and win-8.1. On windows 10 mobile there is the following problem:

When the phone is tilted in the landscape mode the screen scaling/zooming goes wrong. The page is too large and does not fit the screen. The page has the following values:

```
window.innerWidth/innerHeight: 320 x 180
document.documentElement.scrollWidth/scrollHeight: 375 x 569
document.documentElement.clientWidth/clientlHeight: 320 x 569
```

The problem is that the scrollWidth is larger than viewport and the page displays too large.

Is anyone experiencing the same problem? Is there a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be an issue other people are having. I found this question on Stack Overflow with the original poster showing trying their solution: [Windows Phone 8 Viewport issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24007577/windows-phone-8-viewport-issue)

Copy/paste just in case:

```
(function() {
if ("-ms-user-select" in document.documentElement.style && navigator.userAgent.match(/IEMobile\/10\.0/)) {
    var msViewportStyle = document.createElement("style");
    msViewportStyle.appendChild(
        document.createTextNode("@-ms-viewport{width:auto !important}")
    );
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(msViewportStyle);
}
})();
```

Comment: I tried that but it didn't help. After putting the phone to landscape, we get the following values:
window.innerWidth/innerHeight: 320 x 180
document.documentElement.scrollWidth/scrollHeight: 375 x 569
document.documentElement.clientWidth/clientlHeight: 320 x 569

The problem is that the scrollWidth is larger than viewport and the page displays too large. Any other ideas?